# Acumatica UI groups from two different customizations are merging

Tags: acumatica

I have two different customizations, each are adding their own custom field and UI Group on the Inventory Preferences screen. Each field corresponds to a checkbox within each group.  The UI groups have different captions. When building the site customizations, it appears to merge the two groups instead of keeping them separate, and the customization with the highest priority is the one that shows on the screen instead of both, with both checkboxes under it.  How can I get these groups to not merge together?

If I place the groups into different columns on the screen, this doesn't happen, but if they are in the same column, they seem to merge.

This is v2017 R2

Answer (score 0):

I just realized I hadn't posted an update on this yet. Per Acumatica support on 12/26/18, this behavior has been reported to them (AC-51687) previously, and has not been fixed in the latest version as of that date. They stated that they hoped it would be fixed in 2019, but I have not verified this myself yet since we're not using 2019 yet for the customer. You basically need to live with it or workaround it by placing the group elsewhere until a fix exists.